# Remove line break between unordered list and div

Tags: html, css

I currently have a navigation bar that has several items in an unordered list which float left, as well as a dropdown button in a div that floats right. Currently the dropdown menu gets moved below the other menu items, like this:

[image]

I don't want this spacing; I want the div to be aligned with the items in the ul. How can I achieve this?

Note: I can't place the div in the ul because the ul is populated by an outside data source. Here's my current relevant css:

```
.overallContainer {
    display: inline;
}

.menuItems {
    float: left;
}

.dropdownButton {
    float: right;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="overallContainer">
    <ul class="menuItems" id="menuItems" data-sly-list="${topnav.root.listChildren}"> 
        <li> 
            <a href="${item.path}.html">${item.title}</a> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdownButton" data-sly-resource="*resource*"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need your HTML too

Comment: Sorry, I had thought I included it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place both the `ul` and the `div` inside a new `div`; then use `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` on both the `ul` and the nested `div`. (Or Flexbox, if you want.). You'll want to set a `width` on both elements, since by default they will have `100%` which means they won't nicely align with each other. You may also need to consider any default vertical margins, padding, line height on `ul` or `div` elements if you want the text to be perfectly aligned.

Comment: Adding "float: left;" to the overall div did the trick; thanks!